# pytest mark asyncio patch default event loop on startup

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio, pytest-asyncio

I have `my_module.py` that I want to test.

In the module top level code, I have:

```
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# code...
```

test1.py:

```
import mymodule

@pytest.mark.asyncio
def test_mymodule(event_loop):
    await mymodule.func()
```

The problem is that the test freezes, since the event_loop set by `pytest-asyncio` and `mymodule.py` event loop are not the same.

This can be fixed by moving `import mymodule` to inside the test function, but I prefer not to do so.

Is there a way for pytest to patch the default event loop **before** the test code is imported and executed?

Comment: did you happen to find a more elegant solution to your problem, @user3599803 ? I thought of trying instead of get_event_loop, that it could be get_running_loop, except for my use case which I'm kind of forced to use py3.6, I'll have to be more creative...